# Downloading file from oracle takes longer

Tags: c#, oracle, entity-framework, odp.net

I have a functionality where I have to download a PDF file from oracle database, PDF file is stored as LONG RAW in oracle. I am using entity framework with ODP.NET provider to connect to Oracle database. Issue is that it takes longer the very first time when any user download.

For Ex: User A is first person to download file for any product X, it takes around approximately 4-5 mins for 73 kb file.

Once user A has downloaded the file, when user B downloads file for any product Y, it is download within 1-2 seconds for 100 kb file.

The linq that is fired to fetch the PDF file is a simple select query with 4-5 where clause.

I am unable to identify the reason why it is happening. Any thoughts on this will be helpful.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sounds like the oracle engine is creating a query plan the first time.

Comment: 1. Is this oracle-specific? Does the slowdown happen on other data sources? 2. What does the LINQ query look like? 3. What does the SQL command entity framework is sending to the database look like?

Comment: Try this - before the second upload issue a "Alter system flush buffer pool" to clear the cache. Also try this using the query directly in SQL*plus to see if with the cache flushed you get the same result. If after the flush the queries/downloads take the same time and run for the a long time then the issue is your query. If flushing makes no difference then not sure.

Comment: Thanks guys for your comments. @TenG i will try flushing the buffer pool.

Comment: Be VERY careful. FLUSH BUFFER POOL on a production system is NOT a good thing to be running!